# what relations are between my current controlling terminal and `/dev/tty`?

Tags: tty, controlling-terminal, pseudoterminal

On Lubuntu 18.04, I run a shell in lxterminal. Its controlling terminal is the current pseudoterminal slave:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/2
```

I would like to know what relations are between my current controlling terminal `/dev/pts/2` and `/dev/tty`.

1. `/dev/tty` acts like my current controlling terminal `/dev/pts/2`:

   ```
   $ echo hello > /dev/tty
   hello

   $ cat < /dev/tty
   world
   world
   ^C
   ```
2. But they seem to be unrelated files, instead of one being a symlink
   or hardlink to the other:

   ```
   $ ls -lai /dev/tty /dev/pts/2
    5 crw--w---- 1 t    tty 136, 2 May 31 16:38 /dev/pts/2
   13 crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty   5, 0 May 31 16:36 /dev/tty
   ```

For different sessions with different controlling terminals, if
    `/dev/tty` is guaranteed to be their controlling terminals. How can
    it be different controlling terminals, without being a symlink or
    hardlink?

So what are their relations and differences? Any help is much appreciated!

This post is originated from an earlier one [Do the output of command `tty` and the file `/dev/tty` both refer to the controlling terminal of the current bash process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446166/do-the-output-of-command-tty-and-the-file-dev-tty-both-refer-to-the-control)

Comment: As mentioned at that Q&A you link to, `tty` doesn't report the controlling terminal, but the terminal open on stdin if any. See `ps -o tty= -p "$$"` for the controlling terminal (in practice, they are generally the same at the prompt of an interactive shell).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. `ps -o tty= -p "$$"` works well! Is it not possible to get the controlling terminal of the current shell from `/dev/tty`?

Comment: It is possible by opening `/dev/tty`, calling `ioctl(TIOCGDEV, &dev)` to obtain the maj:min devnum of the __real__ tty, and then looking for it through `/dev`. But that will give [ambiguous results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541531/308316) when more than one devpts filesystem is mounted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The `tty` manpage in section 4](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) claims the following:

> The file */dev/tty* is a character file with major number 5 and minor
>          number 0, usually of mode 0666 and owner.group root.tty.  It is a
>          synonym for the controlling terminal of a process, if any.
>
> In addition to the [`ioctl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) requests supported by the device that tty
>          refers to, the [`ioctl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) request `TIOCNOTTY` is supported.
>
> **`TIOCNOTTY`**
>
> Detach the calling process from its controlling terminal.
>
> If the process is the session leader, then `SIGHUP` and `SIGCONT` signals
>          are sent to the foreground process group and all processes in the
>          current session lose their controlling tty.
>
> This [`ioctl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) call works only on file descriptors connected to
>          */dev/tty*.  It is used by daemon processes when they are invoked by a
>          user at a terminal.  The process attempts to open */dev/tty*.  If the
>          open succeeds, it detaches itself from the terminal by using
>          `TIOCNOTTY`, while if the open fails, it is obviously not attached to a
>          terminal and does not need to detach itself.

This would explain in part why `/dev/tty` isn’t a symlink to the controlling terminal: it would support an additional `ioctl`, and there might not be a controlling terminal (but a process can always try to access `/dev/tty`). However the documentation is incorrect: the additional `ioctl` isn’t only accessible *via* `/dev/tty` (see [mosvy’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545948/86440), which also gives a more sensible explanation for the nature of `/dev/tty`).

`/dev/tty` can represent different controlling terminals, without being a link, because the driver which implements it determines what the calling process’ controlling terminal is, if any.

You can think of this as `/dev/tty` being the controlling terminal, and thus offering functionality which only makes sense for a controlling terminal, whereas `/dev/pts/2` etc. are plain terminals, one of which might happen to be the controlling terminal for a given process.

Comment: Thanks. If a process doesn't have a controlling terminal, what does `/dev/tty`mean for the process?

Comment: @Tim Then it can't open it. Please read the manpage carefully.

Answer (score 6):

`/dev/tty` is a "magical" character device which when opened, will return a handle to the current terminal.

Assuming that the controlling terminal is `/dev/pts/1`, a file descriptor opened via `/dev/pts/1` and one opened via `/dev/tty` will refer to the same device; any write, read or other file operation will work the same on either of them.

**In particular, they will accept the same set of ioctls, and `TIOCNOTTY` is not an extra ioctl only available via `/dev/tty`**.

`ioctl(fd, TIOCNOTTY)` works the same on any file descriptor referring to a terminal, provided that it's the controlling terminal of the process which calls it.

It doesn't matter if the descriptor was obtained by opening `/dev/tty`, `/dev/pts/1`, `/dev/ptmx` (in which case the ioctl will act on its corresponding *slave*), or more recently, by a call to `ioctl(master, TIOCGPTPEER, flags)`.

Example:

```
$ cat <<'EOT' >tiocnotty.c
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(int ac, char **av){
        if(ioctl(0, TIOCNOTTY)) err(1, "io(TIOCNOTTY)");
        if(ac < 2) return 0;
        execvp(av[1], av + 1);
        err(1, "execvp %s", av[1]);
}
EOT
$ cc -W -Wall tiocnotty.c -o tiocnotty
$ ./tiocnotty
$ ./tiocnotty </dev/tty
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
$ ./tiocnotty </dev/pts/0
```

Also, it will not really "detach" the current process from the tty; the process will still be able to read from it, a `^C` on the terminal will kill it, etc. Its only effect on a process which is not a session leader is that the tty will no longer be accessible via `/dev/tty`, and it will no longer be listed as the controlling tty in `/proc/PID/stat`:

```
$ ./tiocnotty cat
^C
$ ./tiocnotty cat
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 ./tiocnotty cat
$ ./tiocnotty cat
foo
foo
^D
$ ./tiocnotty cat /dev/tty
cat: /dev/tty: No such device or address
$ ./tiocnotty awk '{print$7}' /proc/self/stat
0
```

[the 7th field of `/proc/<pid>/stat` is the device id of the controlling tty, see `proc(5)`]

If the process calling it is the session leader, it will really detach the session from the tty and will send a `SIGHUP`/`SIGCONT` pair to the foreground process group from the session. But even then, the terminal will **not** be closed, and the process will still be able to read from it, if it survives the `SIGHUP`:

```
$ script /dev/null -c 'trap "" HUP; exec ./tiocnotty cat'
Script started, file is /dev/null
lol
lol
^C^C^C^C^C  # no controlling tty anymore

wtf  
wtf
^D   # but still reading fine from it
Script done, file is /dev/null
```

---

`/dev/tty` is not a symlink like `/dev/stdin` => `/dev/fd/0` => `/proc/self/fd/0` => `/dev/pts/0` because it was invented long before virtual dynamic filesystems like procfs (and long before symlinks in general). And many programs have come to depend on its particular semantics (eg. `/dev/tty` failing with `ENODEV` when the controlling terminal is not accessible).

Comment: Thanks, do you mind if I submit a patch to clarify the manpage?

Comment: That would be great. The earliest system I've tested this on was RedHat 5.1 (Linux 2.0.34) of 21 years go. I don't know if earlier versions really did work as suggested by that manpage.

Comment: I don’t think the manpage has ever been right, the `tty` code has handled `TTIOCNOTTY` in a generic manner since forever.

Comment: Thank you for reply. That is sweet

Comment: I might be totally off here but is this similar to when you use  `&` to put a command to bg and it can still write to terminal?

Comment: @d9ngle The situation is different. The commands started with `&` (either real background jobs, or [background-lite](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509211/308316) as from scripts, shells without job control, etc) are still "attached to" the controlling terminal, they're not even pretending to detach from it.