# How does `sudo` find the TTY?

Tags: linux, sudo

Running the following command in Bash 4, `sudo` prompts for a password:

```
$ echo '' | sudo true
[sudo] password for mike:
```

(I'm not interested in piping my password to `sudo`; this is a demonstration of a behavior I found while troubleshooting.)

It's been my understanding that TTY detection takes place through inspection of
the file descriptor for standard in. The `tty` program supports this:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/26
$ echo '' | tty
not a tty
```

...but `sudo` seems to be using some other mechanism. `setsid` has the intended effect, so my guess is that this is somehow tied to the session.

```
$ setsid sudo true
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

So what is `sudo` up to?

Comment: sudo doesn't read passwords from stdin unless you add `-S` -- `The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.`

Comment: relatedly, sudo opens the TTY directly, if it can. trace pathnames.h _PATH_TTY through to src/tgetpass.c's tgetpass() function, which calls tty_present() which tries to open _PATH_TTY and checks for success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It opens `/dev/tty` (as mentioned by Jeff Schaller, using the `_PATH_TTY` macro), which provides access to the controlling terminal, whichever it is, if there is one. See [what relations are between my current controlling terminal and `/dev/tty`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447197/86440) for details.