# How does `less` take data from stdin while still be able to read commands from user?

Tags: less

As most of you have done many times, it's convenient to view long text using `less`:

```
some_command | less
```

Now its stdin is connected to a pipe (FIFO). How can it still read commands like up/down/quit?

Comment: `less` reads the data to display from stdin, and it reads commands from the tty.  They are different things.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yeah I know. But there's only one standard input stream, right?

Comment: Yes, there is one input stream, and one tty.  `less` reads data from stdin, and commands from the tty.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As mentioned by [William Pursell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4530/william-pursell), `less` reads the user’s keystrokes from the terminal. It explicitly opens `/dev/tty`, the controlling terminal; that gives it a file descriptor, separate from standard input, from which it can read the user’s interactive input. It can simultaneously read data to display from its standard input if necessary. (It could also *write* directly to the terminal if necessary.)

You can see this happen by running

```
some_command | strace -o less.trace -e open,read,write less
```

Move around the input, exit `less`, and look at the contents of `less.trace`: you’ll see it open `/dev/tty`, and read from both file descriptor 0 and whichever one was returned when it opened `/dev/tty` (likely 3).

This is common practice for programs wishing to ensure they’re reading from and writing to the terminal. One example is SSH, *e.g.* when it asks for a password or passphrase.

As [explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452768/86440) by [schily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/120884/schily), if `/dev/tty` can’t be opened, `less` will read from its standard error (file descriptor 2). `less`’s use of `/dev/tty` was introduced in version 177, released on April 2, 1991.

If you try running `cat /dev/tty | less`, as [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452757/how-does-less-take-data-from-stdin-while-still-be-able-to-read-commands-from-u/452763?noredirect=1#comment822507_452763) by [Hagen von Eitzen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/55031/hagen-von-eitzen), `less` will succeed in opening `/dev/tty` but won’t get any input from it until `cat` closes it. So you’ll see the screen blank, and nothing else until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to kill `cat` (or kill it in some other way); then `less` will show whatever you typed while `cat` was running, and allow you to control it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Your computer will explode! It's like the way Kirk and Spock made Mudd's androids crash.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Wow.  A doubly-[useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).  I'm impressed.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm impressed that people are complaining about _the use of pipes on Unix_, which is perhaps the greatest feature of Unix. If anything, `less` should _only_ be able to read from stdin and leave the task of reading from files to other tools, should it not?

Comment: @grawity I think Andrew’s point is that `cat blah |` can be replaced by `< blah`, and even that’s unnecessary in this case since `less blah` works too (well, `less -f /dev/tty`). But reading from `/dev/tty` is a bit of a special case, and all three variants (`cat /dev/tty | less`, `less < /dev/tty` and `less -f /dev/tty`) produce different results.

Comment: Does /dev/tty always point to the right place somehow? I would think you'd need to use /dev/ptsX usually?

Comment: @StarWeaver see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447197/86440) about the difference between `/dev/tty` and `/dev/pts/...`.

Comment: @grawity Standard input is a stream, which means you can't necessarily seek backwards. That would limit the usefulness (or at least efficiency, if `less` buffered its input) if `less` couldn't read from a file directly.

Comment: `less` behaves like `cat` if it's stdout isn't a terminal.  So if you do `echo foo  | strace less | cat`, it's just a transparent no-op filter.  The first TTY system call it makes is `ioctl(1, TCGETS, 0x7ffd7a4b7000)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)`.  It does later make some ioctl system calls on stderr, but doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: @Peter the `ioctl` calls on stderr are used to [determine the screen size](https://sources.debian.org/src/less/487-0.1/screen.c/#L770).

Comment: My point was that they still happen after it's detected that stdout is not a terminal, so it will run non-interactively without touching `/dev/tty`.

Comment: @Peter indeed, it queries the screen size in all cases apparently...

Comment: Any idea why it uses stdout and stderr for the query, instead of `/dev/tty`?  Some kind of sanity check?  Is it possible for stderr and stdout to be open on a terminal other than the controlling TTY, if stdin (or some other FD) is still open on the CTTY?

Comment: @Peter it could be a historical artifact — part of the code which was overlooked when `/dev/tty` was added. I’ve tried finding the diff between 176 and 177 but no luck so far (I’m going to look through Usenet archives next). [This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/less$20177$20$2Fdev$2Ftty/gnu.utils.bug/ttSbSD6wX4Y/6DZLbs-Pj6IJ) is a smoking gun.

Answer (score 29):

UNIX gives two methods to read users input while stdin has been redirected:

- The original method is to read from **stderr**. Stderr is open for writing **and** reading and this is still mentioned in POSIX.
- Later UNIX versions did (around 1979) add a `/dev/tty` driver interface that allows to open the controlling tty of a process. Since there are processes without a controlling tty, it is possible that an attempt to open `/dev/tty` fails. Friendly written software therefore has a fallback to the original method and then tries to read from stderr.

Comment: Read from stderr? Learned something new.

Comment: I'm glad somebody remembers the old ways.

Comment: Is the reason that stderr is used for reading, because it is the least likely to have been redirected? I don't see any other difference between it and stdout (or for that mater stdin, before redirection).

Comment: Yes, it is because this is the file descriptor that has the least chance for being redirected.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: It was / is typical for shells to be running with stdin, stdout, and stderr, all being `dup()`licates of the same file description, though, all opened on the tty.  (Apparently POSIX still requires or suggest (this answer doesn't say) that stderr be a read/write FD, not opened with something like `open("/dev/ttyS0", O_WRONLY)`.  Reading stderr would fail in that case.)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: and BTW, `echo foo | less | cat` just prints foo, because it behaves like `cat` if its stdout is not a terminal.  Maybe so if you add `| grep blah` and forget to remove `less`, your pipeline still works?  Not sure what the idea is there.