# How (and why) use stderr for both reading and writing?

Tags: pipe, stderr

According to [this answer by schily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452768/88106), `less` reads navigation commands from stderr if it's not able to open `/dev/tty`.

This seems puzzling, since I've never seen anything write to another program's stderr stream, and I don't know how I would even accomplish that.

What is the purpose of stderr being open for both reading and writing? And if this is useful, how do I make use of it on modern systems? (Is there some arcane syntax to pipe something into stderr instead of stdin, for instance?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was surprised at first. However after reading the answers, and doing a little investigation, it seems simple. So here is what I have found. (in the end there was no surprise.)

Before redirection stdin, stdout, and stderr are as expected connected to the same device.

```
#ctrl-alt-delor:~$
#↳ ll /dev/std*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jun  3 20:58 /dev/stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jun  3 20:58 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jun  3 20:58 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1

#ctrl-alt-delor:~$
#↳ ll /proc/self/fd/*
lrwx------ 1 richard richard 64 Jun 30 19:14 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/12
lrwx------ 1 richard richard 64 Jun 30 19:14 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/12
lrwx------ 1 richard richard 64 Jun 30 19:14 /proc/self/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/12
```

Therefore after most re-directions (that is if stderr) is not redirected. stderr is still connected to the terminal. Therefore it can be read, to get keyboard input.

The only thing that is stopping the files being used in the unexpected direction is convention, and the pipes are unidirectional.

Another example, try:

```
cat | less
```

This goes wrong after a page, when `less` tries to read the terminal (this is not a surprise, as `cat` is also reading the terminal).

`/dev/tty` is more mysterious, it is not a link into `/proc/self`.

```
#ctrl-alt-delor:~$
#↳ ll /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 Jun 29 09:18 /dev/tty
```

See [what relations are between my current controlling terminal and `/dev/tty`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447197/86440) for an explenation. Thanks to @StephenKitt for the link.

Comment: Regarding `/dev/tty`, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447197/86440).

Answer (score 6):

When you log in, stdin, stdout and stderr are connected to the terminal from where you log in. To be more exact, the tty is typcally opened and stdout and stderr are a result from two `dup(2)` operations on the first file descriptor.  This allows to read from stderr in order to get input from the termnal.

As mentioned in the other answer, programs **read** from stderr in order to get an interactive reply on a question.

Since a user cannot know under which circumstances a program reads from stderr, it is a useless attempt to intentionally write data into stderr from another program.

Note that today programs usually first try to open `/dev/tty` and use stderr only in case that does not work.

Programs that only read from stderr usually have never been modified since before 1979 and such programs usualy contain constructs like:

```
int i 1;
```

or

```
i =* 2;
```

that are not accepted by modern C compilers. As a result, it is most unlikely that you today will find a program that never opens `/dev/tty` but rather reads interactive replies from stderr.

Comment: So if I'm understanding right, the shell connects `stderr` to the tty when `stdin` is redirected (via pipe or other means)? Or just always connects `stderr` to the tty?

Comment: No shell I am aware of reads from something other than stdin.

Comment: So then how does the data get into `stderr` to be read? Something has to set up those streams in the first place, right? (I'm assuming that's the shell, since that's where `stdin` and `stdout` get set up.)

Comment: When you log in, stderr is connected to your login terminal.

Comment: Ah, okay. So just to be sure I'm understanding, if a program decided to read from `stdout` (for no reason except to make a point), would that also be connected to the login terminal?

Comment: If it is not redirected, this works for stdout as well.

Comment: Cool, that explains what I needed to know!

Comment: `i =+ 1` is perfectly valid C, and is equal to `i = (+1)`. Granted, the former is nice candidate for the underhanded C contest.

Comment: OK, it may be that it just creates a warning. I changed the code to something else from C in 1977.

Comment: It seems that I am aware of more shells, since [I _do_ know of at least one shell that reads from other than its standard input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434839/5132).  (-:

Comment: Another reason for not using `zsh`.  In any case, you did not list a shell that reads from stderr, or do you know one?