# Why not write to stdin?

Tags: io-redirection, stdout, stdin

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452819/88106), `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are all initially connected to the same place (same as `/dev/tty`), and the convention of reading from `stdin` and writing to `stdout` and `stderr` is only that: a convention.

In that case, why have separate `stdin` and `stdout` streams, rather than combining them into a single one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FILE pointer such as stdin, stdout and stderr can only contain one underlying file descriptor. Thus if you have a pipeline setup like:

```
ls | grep foo | less
```

Then grep's stdin, stdout and stderr all have different fileno()s because there are two connected pipe()s. Thus there must be different FILEs also.

Comment: This is also the reason that standard error was invented in the first place.  Until 7th Edition, errors were passed down pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

Having an input stream separate from an output stream makes it easier for a program to to write its output at the same time as it's reading its input.

It makes it easier to allow a program to write its output elsewhere than to whence its input came from, using redirections or pipes.

Also, other than being *just a convention*, the three standard I/O streams are also *standard*.  See e.g. [the section on Standard I/O Streams](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05) in the System Interfaces part of the POSIX standard.

[The Rationale for that section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_05) says:

> Although the ISO C standard guarantees that, at program start-up, stdin is open for reading and stdout and stderr are open for writing, this guarantee is contingent (as are all guarantees made by the ISO C and POSIX standards) on the program being executed in a conforming environment. Programs executed with file descriptor 0 not open for reading or with file descriptor 1 or 2 not open for writing are executed in a non-conforming environment. Application writers are warned [...] not to execute a standard utility or a conforming application with file descriptor 0 not open for reading or with file descriptor 1 or 2 not open for writing.