# Reading from stderr in c

Tags: shell, c, file-descriptors, stderr

This is my c program read from stderr i write

```
#include <uninstd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
 char buff[3];
 read(2, buff, sizeof(buff));
 printf("%s", buff");
 return 0;
}
```

My question how can i send a stderr to it.
Most of search show like, in bash redirection

```
command 2> file
```

But this send the stderr to a file.

How can i pass to my program.
Like pip,

```
command 2 "somthing here" ./myprogram
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: `STDERR_FILENO` is an *output* file descriptor. You can't read from it. If you check what `read` returns (which you should always do!) you should probably be getting either an error (`-1`) or end-of-file (`0`). What is the real problem you're having? *Why* do you want to read from standard error?

Comment: @PauloTomé, sure you can, if it's open for writing. At least on the Linux systems I've used, that's the default. e.g. `cat /dev/stderr` works (as does `cat /dev/stdout`), and so does that program, well, at least after all the syntax errors and buffer overflows are fixed.

Comment: `stderr` is open for reading and writing and reading from `stderr` was usual before `/dev/tty` has been introduced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How (and why) use stderr for both reading and writing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452809/how-and-why-use-stderr-for-both-reading-and-writing)

Answer (score 3):

It comes as a surprise to many people, given that most reference books and documentation always refer to standard error as an output, that it is in fact usually *already open for read+write*.  Your program very much *can* read from file descriptor 2.

(Note: In this answer I am using the actual file descriptor numbers.  The *C streams* such as `stderr` need not actually correspond with these file descriptors, as a program can change them, and it adds a layer of confusion to talk about what the C streams do.  Your program is using `read()`.)

## File descriptor 2 is open for reading and writing

For programs in login sessions where no redirection has been used in a parent process, file descriptor 2 (standard error) is typically a duplicate of file descriptor 0 (standard input).  They both reference the same underlying *file description*, which is typically the terminal of the login session (opened and duplicated by `ttymon` or, on older systems, `getty` at the very start of the session).

If you read from file descriptor 2, you get the same input as if you had read from file descriptor 0.

BTW: Reading from file descriptor 2 was frequently done for things like password input; before the `/dev/tty` device was introduced, around 1977.
The reason for reading from file descriptor 2 was to obtain input from the original terminal when file descriptor 0 had been redirected elsewhere (as is the case in the middle of a pipeline, for example).

Even though `/dev/tty` has been available for a long time now, over 40 years, POSIX still requires file descriptor 2 to be open for reading as well.

## What your program is not doing

Reading from the file descriptor 2 output of another program is a different thing. You canot easily do that *by itself*, without merging standard output with standard error.  It usually involves a series of `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3` or suchlike swaps.  A few shells permit pipes on the output file descriptor 2 by calling

```
prog1 2| prog2
```

But such shells are rare, and that's not what *your* program needs in any case.

## Sending input to your program

If you want your program, reading from file descriptor 2, to read from something *other* than from the terminal, you of course redirect that file descriptor.  You *could* use the normal *input* redirection syntax (the `<` operator in the shell), but libraries in your program, or even other code that you have written elsewhere, will have assumptions that they can write to this file descriptor.

The shell allows you to use the `<>` redirect operator that explicitly opens a file for both reading and writing.  This is what you use when redirecting your program's file descriptor 2.

```
./myprogram 2<>filename
```

Outwith shell redirection, there are plenty of tools that allow manipulation of file descriptors.  For example: With Laurent Bercot's chain-loading [`redirfd`](https://www.skarnet.org/software/execline/redirfd.html) tool, that comes with execline, this redirection looks more like your hypothesis:

```
redirfd -u 2 filename ./myprogram
```

There is also shell syntax in the likes of the Bourne Again and Z shells (but not the Almquist shells) to provide "here documents" and "here strings" to file descriptor 2.  Note that file descriptor 2 is opened *read only* by these shells in this case.

```
./myprogram 2<<< "here string"
```

Answer (score 1):

`stderr` is meant for writing, not reading. Sometimes it is a `dup`licate of `stdin` (e.g. when all 3 in/out/err are connected to terminal). To read stderr of another program, you redirect the stderr of that program, to the stdin of another.

e.g. to directs `stdout` to a file, and `stderr` to `./myprograms`'s `stdin`.

```
command 2>&1 >a_file | ./myprogram
```

Comment: You are mistaken, `stderr` is open for reading and writing.

Comment: @schily But you can not always read from it. You should expect it to be an output.

Comment: There are a few exceptions, when you cannot read from stderr. These exceptions are usually hit when you did redirect `stderr`.  The shell however allows to use the `<>`  redirect operator that explicitly opens a file for reading and writing.

Answer (score 1):

With shells like `bash` and `zsh` (But not plain POSIX `sh`), you can redirect one program's standard error to another program's standard input via `firstprogram 2> >(second program)`.

Example:

```
$ perl -E 'say "perl stdout"; warn "perl stderr\n"' 2> >(awk '{print "awk", $0}')
perl stdout
awk perl stderr
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the shell set up an input redirection for `stderr`, you'd use `<`, `<<` or `<<<` and prefix the file descriptor number:

```
./myprog 2< somefile.txt
```

or

```
./myprog 2<<< "some text"
```

Though if you redirect `stderr` like that, the program can't *output* to it, which will mean you won't see any error messages the program (or any libraries it uses) might try to print, and in addition the program will get errors for trying to write those messages.

You may want to reconsider if there would be some other way of doing what ever it is you're doing. In the least, consider using e.g. fd 3 if the idea is to provide some input to the program.