# Linux ioctl VT_GETSTATE fails if process is run manually

Tags: root, tty, c, sysvinit, ioctl

I'm using the `ioctl` syscall on Linux to get the current tty in a C program.

I don't know why the `ioctl` fails if the program is run manually (as root)  while it works as expected if the `init.d` script is used (as root). Note that I tried using either an SSH connection or the terminal application in the GUI session. The only way I managed to make the program running correctly is by switching to a virtual terminal (CTRL+Fx where x is a number) and run the command from there. I tested the program on RHEL8 and RHEL6. On RHEL8 the `ioctl` returns `ENOTTY` ("Inappropriate ioctl for device") while on RHEL6 the error is `EINVAL` ("Invalid argument").

I wrote this test program to debug the issue but it seems to behave differently from the main program:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/vt.h>
#include <linux/kd.h>

int main()
{

    long tty = -1;
    long fd = 0;
    int result = 0;
    struct vt_stat ttyinfo;

    fd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    if(fd <= 0) 
    {
        printf("Trying tty0\n");
        fd = open("/dev/tty0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

        if(fd <= 0)
        {
            printf("[open] error = %s\n" , strerror(errno) );
            return -1;
        }
    }

    result = ioctl(fd, VT_GETSTATE, &ttyinfo);

    if (result == 0) 
    {
        tty = ttyinfo.v_active;
        printf("tty: %d\n" , tty);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("[ioctl] error = %s\n" , strerror(errno) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: This is only a piece of code, the real program is daemonized and perform much more operations.

**RHEL8:**

If the command (real application) is run from the UI or SSH /dev/tty and /dev/tty0 are tried and the reported error is: Inappropriate ioctl for device.

**RHEL6:**
If the command (real application) is run from the UI or SSH /dev/tty only is used and the reported error is: Invalid argument

Do you know why this is happening ?
I tried to add the daemonization to the test program but while the test program keep working the main program don't. There must be something else that the main program is doing and the test program don't.

Comment: what about  `cat /sys/class/tty/tty0/active`? btw, I cannot reproduce your problem, either on centos7 or rhel8. please post a complete example.

Comment: I updated the code i figured out that the test program is working while the real application is failing. There must be something that I failed to report into the test program.

Comment: @mosvy is the file /sys/class/tty/tty0/active present on all kernel versions ? The application was written years ago and I noticed that this file is not present on RHEL6.

Comment: available since this [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=fbc92a3455577ab17615cbcb91826399061bd789) (<2.6.39, 2011)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is happening because you’re running your program from a terminal which isn’t a virtual console. [`/dev/tty` is a special device which provides access to the controlling terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447211/86440), and that’s not necessarily a virtual console; but the `ioctl` you’re using only works on virtual consoles.

Your program will work reliably if you ensure that `fd` points at a [virtual console](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_console.2.html), and the easiest way to do that when running as root is to open `/dev/tty0`, which [is the active virtual console](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/vt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  long tty = -1;
  long fd = 0;
  int result = 0;
  struct vt_stat ttyinfo;

  fd = open("/dev/tty0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
  if (fd < 0) {
    perror("Error opening /dev/tty0");
    return 1;
  }
  result = ioctl(fd, VT_GETSTATE, &ttyinfo);
  if (result == 0) {
    tty = ttyinfo.v_active;
    printf("Active tty: %ld\n", tty);
  } else {
    perror("ioctl failed");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt . The program worked as expected when I run it from a virtual terminal (I switched from the UI terminal to a console terminal with CTRL+F3). I tried to switch to tty0 but the problem was the same, maybe the error was different but the program wasn't working.

Comment: Could you clarify what the error was? I’ve added the program I used to verify my answer.

Comment: I updated the question with such information. The errors and the tty devices were different in the OS used to run the test program

Comment: Your program fails because you’re only trying `/dev/tty0` if you fail to open `/dev/tty`; but the latter won’t fail. To determine the active VT, you need to skip `/dev/tty` entirely and open `/dev/tty0`.

Comment: I don't know why the code was written in this way. Does the tty terminal have a specific usage ?  Do you have good links on this topic ? I don't know much about virtual terminals.

Comment: See the first link in my answer. `tty` *isn’t* a virtual terminal.